# Module Bootstrap not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-framework-modules, zend-application

I have a Person Module and here is my bootstrap:

application/modules/person/Bootstrap.php

```
class Person_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
    protected function _initAutoload() {
        $personLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource( array (
            'basePath'  =>  APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/person',
            'namespace' =>  'Person',
            'resourceTypes' =>  array (
                                        'form'  =>  array ( 'path'  =>  'forms/', 'namespace' =>  'Form_' ),
                                        'model' =>  array ( 'path'  =>  'models/', 'namespace' =>  'Model_' )
                                      );
        ));
        return $personLoader ;
    }
} // end class
```

But whenever I go to any controller/action of this module, it is not considering this bootstrap. Therefore I am unable to access forms in this module like:

```
class Person_Form_MyForm extends Zend_Form {

   // elements
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` is for your application `Bootstrap`, which goes into `application/Bootstrap.php`

When creating a module bootstrap, you should extend `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` class.